# Cannot find method createEvent(string,string,string,object). (line 51, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

Looking for some help on this script that I got on here. I have tweaked the code from the original but have not changed line 47.  I am getting this error on execution. - Cannot find method createEvent(string,string,string,object). (line 47, file "Code")

```
function exportEvents() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headerRows = 1;  // Number of rows of header info (to skip)
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var calId ="furnish.com_ksuv182d3o843go31gotmejigk@group.calendar.google.com";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if (i < headerRows) continue; // Skip header row(s)
      var row = data[i];
      var title = row[5];           // Second column
      var tstart = row[3];
      var tstop = row[4];
      var loc = row[8];
      var desc = row[7];
      var id = row[0];              // Sixth column == eventId

      // Check if event already exists, update it if it does
      try {
        var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
      }
      catch (e) {
      // do nothing - we just want to avoid the exception when event doesn't exist
      }
      if (!event) {
        /* cal.createEvent(title, new Date("March 3, 2010 08:00:00"), new 
        Date("March 3, 2010 09:00:00"), {description:desc,location:loc}); */
        var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop,{description:desc,location:loc}).getId();
        row[0] = newEvent;  // Update the data array with event ID
      }
      else {
        event.setTitle(title);
        event.setDescription(desc);
        event.setLocation(loc);
        // event.setTime(tstart, tstop); // cannot setTime on eventSeries.
        // ... but we CAN set recurrence!
        var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().times(1);
        event.setRecurrence(recurrence, tstart, tstop);
    }
    debugger;
  }
  // Record all event IDs to spreadsheet
  range.setValues(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this:

```
var tstart = new Date(row[3]);
var tstop = new Date(row[4]);
```

Just to make sure that they are dates and not strings that look like dates.